# PHPのPDOのCRUDで「複雑なSQLにも対応しているようなラッパークラス」のライブラリ

Tags: php

**PHPのPDOのCRUDで、複雑なSQLにも対応しているようなラッパークラスのライブラリはないでしょうか？**

**分からないので参考にしたい点1.**
・WHEREでAND条件が複数あって、bindParamも渡す時の実装方法

**分からないので参考にしたい点2.**
・複雑なSQL(例えば自己結合など)への対応方法

---

**追記**
・(フレームワークを使用しない前提で)PDOでCRUDする際、なるべく効率よく実装したいと思い、質問しました
・毎回同じようなことを繰り返すので、DB処理に特化したクラスを探しています

・コードは理解したいので、フレームワークよりなるべくシンプルなライブラリの方が良いかなと思っています
(気に入ったクラスがあればそのまま使用したいが、なければ作成してみる予定なので)

・bindParamは(bindValueも含む)引数を渡すという意味で書きました

・SymfonyもLaravelも使用したことはないのですが、DB部分だけ独立して使用可能でしょうか？

・「O/Rマッパー」と「クエリビルダ」の違いが分かりません
・生SQLを記述するかどうかの違いですか？
・もしそうだとしたら、「O/Rマッパー」を探しているのですが、そもそも「O/Rマッパー」は全てのSQLに対応しているのでしょうか？
・基本的に、どんな複雑なSQLでも「O/Rマッパー」は対応可能でしょうか？

Comment: ラッパークラスの指す範囲は広いですが、O/Rマッパーでしょうか、クエリビルダでしょうか。参考にしたいとありますが、そういったクラスを実装でもするのでしょうか？bindValueではなくbindParamでないといけないのでしょうか？ / どういったものを求めているのかよくわからないのですが、大手フレームワークであるSymfonyやLaravelで使っているものでは不足でしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 追記しました